# Watchdog service doesn't kick /dev/watchdog in OSMC

Tags: osmc, watchdog

I have installed `watchdog` service on OSMC/Raspberry Pi 3. It starts now automatically, but doesn't touch the `/dev/watchdog` device.

How I check this:

```
ls -l /dev/watchdog
crw------- 1 root root 10, 130 Dec 17 14:44 /dev/watchdog
ls -l /dev/watchdog
crw------- 1 root root 10, 130 Dec 17 14:44 /dev/watchdog
ls -l /dev/watchdog
crw------- 1 root root 10, 130 Dec 17 14:44 /dev/watchdog
```

When I touch the device file manually:

```
touch /dev/watchdog
```

the file date is changed and if I stop touching this file, the computer reboots after 15 seconds.

Uncommented lines of `/etc/watchdog.conf` file:

```
max-load-1      = 24
watchdog-device = /dev/watchdog
realtime        = yes
priority        = 1
```

and nothing more, because I want only to check if watchdog service writes to `/dev/watchdog` file and because I haven't found reliable PIDs to watch.

How to make the service to write in `/dev/watchdog` ?